# Exporting to Excel with JasperReports: How to add AutoFilter for columns

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, autofilter

I am using this code for create report in MS Excel format:

```
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
```

From there I don't know if it's possible to tell JasperReports to apply an auto filter on each column.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue i.e in my spreadsheet(.xls) I wanted to add auto filter to all the columns(15), so I have added one property(Properties expression )name = net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter and value as 'Start' at first column header and same property with value as End at last column header and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'Exporter Parameters' pane and make sure none of the 'Start' or 'Stop' options are set for Auto Filter. Choose the empty space in the related list box (see the attached image). Then run the report again. This time you should see the filters in the right places.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/6876

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports engine can is able to apply autofilters for columns for MS Excel output format. For applying autofilters we have to use [***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter) property. We should apply this property for header cells. It is possible to set filter for only one column or for the several columns.

### Working example

#### Datasource

I used the csv datasource in this sample:

```
language,framework
Java,Guava
Java,Lombok
Java,JasperReports
Java,Spring
Java,Vaadin
C#,ASP.NET MVC
C#,NancyFX
C#,Automapper
JavaScript,AngularJS
JavaScript,React
JavaScript,jQuery
```

The name of data adapter for this datasource in the example below is *frameworks.csv*

#### The report's template

I used *Jaspersoft Studio* (JSS) for designing a report template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="excel_filter" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="b521f87a-96ed-43bd-80bd-c7b81ef2e8aa">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="frameworks.csv"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="language" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="framework" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30" uuid="6b8ba60b-3df3-4c78-a780-79ee493ca5f8">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter" value="Start"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Language]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30" uuid="731ba580-2168-49f6-b844-d02549d3d83c">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter" value="End"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Framework]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30" uuid="7bf9acec-b13a-4261-91c1-0bf6f2c9c784"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{language}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30" uuid="d15bd48e-77ee-43df-b11f-4ec1a65811c0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{framework}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I've used the Detail band for showing data. For the first column I set the **Start** value to the ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter*** property for *staticText* in *Column Header* band (will be the column header in Excel file) and the **End** value  for the second (last) column.

In case using of setting property for only one column the only one filter will be created.

We can easy set property with help of context menu *"XLS Tags -> Autofilter -> Start (End)"* in *JSS*.

[image]

#### Output result

The generated output file in MS Excel format contains autofilters for both columns. The file was generated with help of JSS.

[image: Filters in MS Excel file]

---

#### Notes:

More information about applying different features for exported Excel files can be found on [vendor site](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures)